# How to assign image in an variable?

Tags: image, image-processing, matlab

I want to develop an application that can read and display images in sequence.
I have read the image with syntax:

```
ImageSeq(:,:,i) = imread(image_name); % load image
```

and

```
 I=ImageSeq(:,:,100);
```

and when i wanna assign variable a with the image I, the displayed image is only white..

```
    gambar=(I,[]);
```

and there is an error messege appear

```
"gambar=(I,[]);
         |
  Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.
```

How to solve it? How to display the image by calling the variable "gambar" in matlab?

Comment: Where did you get `gambar=(I,[]);`???  Do you mean `imshow(I,[])`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `imshow(I,[])`.  If you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox, use `imagesc`.